# Word for a nostalgic anachronism?

Tags: synonyms

"Vintage" is close to what I'm looking for. Maybe "anachronism" is too strong, but I'm looking for a word that describes something that becomes desirable since it is no longer in use, like receiving a letter in the mail.

Comment: Quaint maybe? if it's formal/prudish maybe victorian.

Comment: An _antiquity_ is the closest I can get. It covers the "no longer in use" part but not so much the desire.

Comment: Sounds like something that is retro.  Old and anachronistic, but somehow back in style.

Comment: [*I went on to my wagon, puzzled more than somewhat, to borrow a **quaintism***.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quaintism%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: [Now there's a man whose name fits him like a well-oiled boot.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quaintism%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22him+like+a+well-oiled+boot%22) I don't think "oiled boots" are much in use these days, but I bet they're desirably comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

I think "[evocative](https://www.google.com/search?q=evocative)" might fit what you're looking for.

> adjective: evocative bringing strong images, memories, or feelings to mind.

So perhaps an *evocative letter*?

Comment: Best answer yet. +1.

Comment: It's customary to link to an online dictionary definition.

Comment: I will update once I have a computer with internet access (phone right now), my apologies I was unaware, first answer here.

Answer (score 0):

What about "period piece"?  From google:

> period piece (noun): an object or work that is set in or strongly reminiscent of an earlier historical period.